# Azure DevOps Pipeline passing variables between jobs

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've been tirelessly trying to make my pipeline work according to the

- [Job to job dependencies yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-within-one-stage).
- [Troubleshoot pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#variables-having--single-quote-appended)
- [Job to job dependencies context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-within-one-stage)

They claim that if I do the following step I should be able to access `Name` across multiple jobs:

```yaml
pool:
  name: ubuntu

parameters:
- name: sourceArtifactPath
  type: string

jobs:
- job: Setup
  steps:
  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Name;isOutput=true]$(basename ${{ parameters.sourceArtifactPath }})"
    name: SetVariables
    displayName: "Set Pipeline Variables"
  - script: echo $(SetVariables.Name)

- job: DoStuff
  dependsOn: Setup
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Important work has beed done"

- job: Upload
  dependsOn: DoStuff
  variables:
    artifactName:  $[ dependencies.Setup.outputs['SetVariables.Name'] ]
  steps:
  - script: echo $(artifactName)
    displayName: "Print Filename"
```

and it works for the reference inside same job, however when I try to access `Setup.SetVariables.Name` from different job all im getting is:

```
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo 
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
```

please help.

some questions look similar but are not exactly the same like:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910922/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-output-variable-from-one-job-to-another)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000201/azure-devops-passing-variables)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue using your YAML snippet, although I had to make a few indentation fixes (which I believe is the issue here). `artifactName` seems to print out in `Upload` job

Comment: I wish that was the case. Following you suggestion I auto-formatted the yaml, unfortunatelly nothing has change.

Comment: Well it works for me, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c8yt.png). Also, `name: ubuntu` is this a self hosted agent?

Comment: yes , it's 20.04 image on couple of build agent that are labeled as ubuntu

Comment: Your YAML (pasted in the question) isn't valid. You might want to paste the YAML again. It's [not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRGH4.png). I am surprised how that even ran in ADO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference a variable from the `Setup` job, you need to declare you're dependent on that job.

```
- job: Upload
  dependsOn: 
  - Setup
  - DoStuff
```

It's not enough to declare your job depends on `DoStuff` which declares its dependency on `Setup`.

Comment: Yes, I've just discovered that and wanted to just write that. It's not written anywhere in the documentation which is infuriating to debug.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me. Important part is `isOutput=true`. Add this while defining variable otherwise you wont be able to view/print/echo the variable

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'master'
pool:
  mypool

jobs:
  # Set an output variable from job A
  - job: A
    steps:
    - script: |
        #!/bin/bash        
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvar1;isOutput=true]True"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvar2;isOutput=true]hello"
      name: setvarStep
  # Map the variable into job B
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    variables:
      myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myvar1'] ]  
      myVarFromJobA1: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myvar2'] ]  
    steps:
    - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA)
      name: echovar
    - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA1)
      name: echovar1
```